# How to do rasa nlu, stories data validation and updation effectively?

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I am developing APIs/ Frontend to add new data, stories, responses, entities, add actions , train bot, deploy bot etc .

I am updating backend nlu.md, stories.md, domain.yml etc and then execute rasa train, rasa shell etc in the backend.

Is there any rasa command available to add nludata effectively?
Currently, i am using python to add intents, entities etc to nlu.md file.

Logic has become complicated.

Below is sample code to add intents:

```
 pathnlu = bot_name + "/data/nlu.md"
            print("Bot id is", args['bot_id'])
            if str(os.path.exists(pathnlu)):
                f = open(pathnlu, "a")
                f.write("\n")
                f.write("## intent:")
                f.write(intent.intent_name)
                f.write("\n")
                f.write("- ")
                f.write(intent.intent_description)
                f.close()
                print("Intent ", intent.intent_name, " Created ")
            else:
                print("Unable to Create Intent")
```

Below is a sample code to add entities :

```
 pathnlu = bot_name + "/data/nlu.md"
                print("Bot id is", args['bot_id'])
                if str(os.path.exists(pathnlu)):
                    f = open(pathnlu, "a")
                    f.write(intent.intent_description + "(" + entities + ")" + remaining_intent)
                    f.close()
                    print("entity", entities, " Added")
                else:
                    print("Unable to add entities")
```

But, I am looking for some simple and robust way to accomplish it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Interactive learning in RASA, where your files will get updated
> and In this mode, you provide feedback to your bot while you talk to
> it. This is a powerful way to explore what your bot can do, and the
> easiest way to fix any mistakes it makes. One advantage of machine
> learning-based dialogue is that when your bot doesn’t know how to do
> something yet, you can just teach it!

**How to do it?** - https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/interactive_learning/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this link, it will be helpful in interactive learning but, I want some commands like rasa train or rasa shell, which updates the entities or slots directly into the nlu.md file.  i.e rasa --add-entities entity_name intent_name .